# Hive CREATE TABLE LIKE another table set partition key

Tags: hadoop, hive

I have `table1` without partition key, I want to create a `table2`, with the same schema as `table1`, but set one column "`datestr`" as partition key. How can I write the `CREATE TABLE LIKE` query to do so?

```
table1:

datestr, userID, transaction, balance




table2 (set datestr as partition key):

datestr, userID, transaction, balance
```

Answer (score 2):

The `CREATE TABLE LIKE` DDL doesn't support setting partitions

I believe you can perform a CTAS query like so

```
Create table table2 (userID INT, transaction STRING, balance DECIMAL) 
Partitioned by (datestr STRING) 
as 
select userID, transaction, balance, datestr 
From table1;
```

Of course add the column types accordingly

Comment: The thing is transaction is a "struct of array" and "array of many other nested structs and arrays" giant type. I just can't expand the schema... Is there a way to assign the partition key without having to specify the types?

Comment: I assume `datestr` is a string. Hive can handle structs and arrays fine... You're not partitioning on them, but you must specify them in order to create any table, partitioned or not

Comment: Also, you can literally copy the `SHOW CREATE TABLE` command from the other table, and then add the partition for the new table, then perform an `INSERT INTO`